# class as a variable in Java

Tags: java, class, variables

I've been looking at some code and I'm wondering if anyone can explain how this works for example

```
public class DataTable {

}
```

Then it is used in another class

```
public class UsingDatatable {
    public DataTable checktables = null;
}
```

Why does this other class use another class as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant why UsingDataTable class **can** make instances of DataTable class, there are a number of reasons.

- First, DataTable has access to the class. It could be because they share the same package or UsingDataTable 'imports' the DataTable class.
- Second, it can be instantiated since it's not final. Thus, each instance(object) inherits
  all the non-static attributes implemented which could be for some later use.
- Third, objects can be constructed from it even if you don't create a constructor in it unless the contsructor is declared private( Java compiler will create by default a public constructor).
- Fourth, why a DataTable object is declared as a field in UsingDataTable depends on the implementer. However, in all cases each UsingDataTable object will have its own copy of the checktable field.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **has-a** relation, also called **Composition**. In this example, `UsingDatatable` has a `DataTable`. The following example will help you better understand the concept.

```
public class Address{
    private String houseNo;
    private String streetNo;
}

public class Person{
    private Address address = null;
}
```

This example says that the `Person` has an `Address`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called composition and is aimed at making use of fields and methods of the other class.
For more details please take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

> In computer science, object composition is a way to combine simple objects or data types into more complex ones. Compositions are a critical building block of many basic data structures, including the tagged union, the linked list, and the binary tree, as well as the object used in object-oriented programming.

for example :

```
public class Main {
    void aMethod(int a) {
        Useful u = new Useful();
        int c = u.usefulMethod(Useful.MYCONST, a);
    }
}

class Useful {
    public final static int MYCONST = 10;
    public int usefulMethod(int i, int j) {
        return i * j;
    }
}
```

---

To be more specific about your question (that seems like an example for the notion of object composition), `UsingDatatable` is creating an object of the `Datatable` to use it (however it seems to be an empty class, but in reality it always contains useful things).

Answer (score 0):

All variables must either:

- contain a primitive value, or
- reference an instance of a class.

In your example, `checktables` references an *instance* of the `DataTable` class (not the class itself).